# Recover deleted package from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, recover

Is it possible to recover a deleted package from SQL Server Management Studio?

I deleted by mistake when I was going to run it. The delete option is right below the Run Package option and I pressed the wrong one by 1px and then pressed enter by reflex without reading the confirmation pop-up that came up!

I didn't originally build this package so I can't rebuild it so any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: [Package Backup and Restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141699.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link. How can I find out if the package was stored in the DB or the file system?

Comment: If you deleted it from the SSMS Package Explorer View, it is very likely that it was deployed in the DB. You could create a new dummy sql server instance to restore the MSDB backup and inspect the contents.

Comment: I'd recommend to move this to [dba.se] for better answers.

Comment: I just confirmed the package was inside of the MSDB folder in Integration Services. I don;t have much experience with packages and no idea how to restore a DB from a bkp. Can you point me in the right direction please? And where is the bkp located?